# Maps sending weakly convergent sequences to weakly convergent sequences are continuous?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, continuity

Well, the question is in the title. I understand that they are continuous in the weak topology, but can't see that it must hold for the norm topology.

Please help me.

Comment: You understand they are continuous in the weak topology?  Well, at least they are sequentially continuous.

Comment: Similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/241528/822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces. Suppose the linear map $T:X\rightarrow Y$ is unbounded. Then  there exist norm one elements $x_n\in X$ such that $\Vert Tx_n\Vert\ge n^2$. Consider the sequence $(x_n/n)$. This sequence coverges in norm to $0$ and is thus weakly convergent.

Now, if $T$ is weak-weak continuous, it would follow that $(T(x_n/n))$ is weakly convergent. However, a weakly convergent sequence is norm bounded, and $\Vert T (x_n/n)\Vert \ge n$ for each positive integer $n$.